# Blazor server - localization dlls (xxx.resources.dll) missing inside the output folder when run dotnet publish --configuration release

Tags: localization, blazor-server-side, dotnet-build, resource-dll

I have a blazor server application with 2 localization resource files with following names
App.no.resx and App.resx, but these were missing when do the dotnet publish with below command,

```
dotnet publish --configuration release
```

but the resource dlls are generated inside "no" folder when run the build from VS2019

Note - Both localization resource files are set as 'embedded resource' and 'do not copy'

can someone please advise me how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Issue was in the resource file name, file name should be "App.nn.resx"